# Reopen -- Employer wants me to learn new language/system - how can I refuse to do this?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-request

[Employer wants me to learn new language/system - how can I refuse to do this?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/72424/2322)

I understand people may dislike the OP's motivation or disagree with them, but this question feels squarely on topic.

Hoping to get a reopen votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree.

I was one of the ones who voted to close.  Enderland is right, I have voted to reopen.  We need to separate the motivation/attitude/wisdom of the querent from the quality of the question.

For that reason, I have voted to reopen.

Comment: No argument, but the answer remains "unless you are willing to get a bad review, quit, or be fired over it you can't, and if you hope to survive in this industry you should expect to be continuously learning."

Comment: @keshlam YEP, that's the nature of the beast

Comment: I just cast the 5th reopen vote.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, I still disagree.

This might not be noticeable from a perspective of someone living under the rule of at-will employment, but to me this is a legal question. I know countries where this would constitute something like constructive dismissal when your job description changes and you don't like it. He *may* well have the option to be "laid off" with all that comes with it. I don't know. I don't know the legal system there. That's why I voted to close it as "get legal advice".

Comment: This is a matter of interpretation, i red this as "how refuse to be moved to new language / system professionally ?". Of course an answer of such question should first start by "legally you can't".  But that doesn't mean there is nothing to be said in the workplace about it.

Comment: @Walfrat What if the answer for his jurisdiction is "forget doing it professionally, legally you *can*"?

Comment: Then you could add "for the specific legal aspect go to law.SE". If it's not possible professionally, that's an answer